# The multivariable chain rule and functions that depend on themselves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am attempting to show that if $z = z(x,y)$, then $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}.\qquad\qquad(1)$$  This negative sign does not strike me as intuitive, given the close resemblance this formula has to the single-variable chain rule.

From the multivariable chain rule, $$\frac{\partial z(x,y(x,z))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(x,z)}{\partial x}\qquad\qquad(2)$$ which is equivalent to $(1)$ if $$\frac{\partial z(x,y(x,z))}{\partial x} = 0,\qquad\qquad(3)$$ but how can $(3)$ be sensibly justified?  How can one show that $z(x,y(x,z))$ only depends on $z$, and is not such reasoning rather circular?

Comment: In short, your notation led you to forget that $z$ could be derived down to zero w.r.t $x$. Perhaps you should accept @M.Strochyk's answer.

Comment: Can you add explanation to what you mean by 'differentiating $z$ down to zero with respect to $x$'?

Comment: Oh, it's just that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $z=\varphi(x,\, y).$ Then the equation $$z-\varphi(x,\, y)=0$$
defines an implicit function $y(x,\, z)$ of *independent* variables $x$ and $z,$ therefore $$z-\varphi(x,\, y(x,\,z))\equiv{0}.\tag{*}$$
Differentiate $(*)$ with respect to $x,$ taking into account that $z$ is independent on $x$ (i.e. $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}=0$):
$$\frac{\partial{\varphi(x,\, y(x,\,z))}}{\partial{x}}+ \frac{\partial{\varphi(x,\, y(x,\,z))}}{\partial{y}} \cdot \frac{\partial{y(x,\,z)}}{\partial{x}}=0.$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial{\varphi(x,\, y(x,\,z))}}{\partial{x}}=- \frac{\partial{\varphi(x,\, y(x,\,z))}}{\partial{y}} \cdot \frac{\partial{y(x,\,z)}}{\partial{x}}.$$

Comment: Thanks M.  Now how does one justify replacing $\varphi$ with $z$ in your final equation?  To arrive there we have said $\partial z/\partial x = 0$, but replacing $\varphi$ with $z$ states otherwise.

Comment: Notation $z=\varphi(x,\, y)$ was used to avoid confusing between _variable_ $z$ and function of variables $x$ and $y.$ If $D$ is some region in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ then $S=\{(x,\, y,\, \varphi(x,\,y))\colon\;\;\; (x,\,y)\in D \}$ is an surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and under some additional assumptions on function $\varphi$ is possible to express the variable, say $y$ in two other ($x$ and $z$).